# Getting stuck on Index Match Match in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match

[image]Im getting stuck with an index match that I want to do. I want to look up years on both rows and columns and drop in the value from a table on the left. Please find attached a screenshot.

[image]

The Code that im using is :
`=INDEX($F$2:$F$64,MATCH($H8,$E$2:$E$64,0),MATCH($H8,$J$1:$BS$1,0))`

Comment: You are passing a column reference into an index of only one column.

Comment: I don't understand how your data is to be placed.  You only have one year and are trying to correlate it to two.  can you explain more what you expect and why.

Comment: Change formula to `I1:BS1` and not with `J1:BS1`. This should fix it.

Comment: That worked! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$64,MATCH($H8,$E$2:$E$64,0),MATCH($H8,$I$1:$BS$1,0))
```

Comment: This will still return an error when ever the second MATCH returns anything greater than 1.